# Need some help interpreting this recursion code

Tags: java, recursion

I am new to recursion and my teacher gave us this code to examine:

```
public long rudolph(long a, long b){
 if(b==0)
   return a;
 else 
   return rudolph(b, a % b);
}
```

I tried to follow the logic by using different values for a and b each time but I can't make sense of the outcomes.  How to figure this out without running it? Basically trying to figure out what this code does in general.

example:

```
if a = 9 and b = 7:
return rudolph(7,2);
return rudolph(2,1);
return rudolph(1,0);
return 1

if a = 10 and b = 5:
return rudolph(5,0);
return 5

if a = 5 and b = 2:
return rudolph(2,1);
return rudolph(1,0);
return 1
```

Comment: Show us what values you computed

Comment: The last example is not correct.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to get a piece of paper and a pencil and record values for a and b at every call. Start with small(er) (a=2,b=3 for example) to see where and how the recursion stops and then you can work your way up from there.

EDIT: Show us what you've tried and we can try to point you in the right direction if you really can't figure it out (there's a difference between being lazy and really not understanding).

Comment: @user3195991 You've made an error on the rudolph(5,2). 5%2 = 1, not 2.

Comment: @user3195991 so all of the examples you posted are correct. Do you see what the final values signify?

Answer (score 0):

The function return the [Greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)